# Как получить товары в названии которых есть строка?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Получаю товары таким образом, но сортировка по name не срабатывает, по категории дня и набор работает, как можно исправить поиск по имени?

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => [
    'relation' => 'AND',
      [
        'name__like'=> $product_name,
      ],
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('nabor'),
      ],
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $day,
      ],
  ]
] );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в `wp_query` нет параметра для поиска по подстроке, но вы можете использовать для этого фильтр `posts_where`

например вот так

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'search_by_title', 10, 2 );

function search_by_title( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $need_title = $wp_query->get( 'name__like' );
    if ( $need_title ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $need_title) ) . '%\'';
    }

    return $where;
}

$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'name__like'=> $product_name,
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('nabor'),
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $day,
        ],
    ]
] );
```